# webcam see my body movement and run a windows7 command

Tags: windows-7, webcam, kinect

Is it possible to recognize body movement with a laptop webcam or a Kinect and go to the next slide in PowerPoint 2010 or run a command in Windows 7?

I want it so that when I move my hand, PowerPoint will go to next slide. In other words:

1. Webcam sees me
2. Webcam detects my movement
3. Command executes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [Camera Mouse](http://cameramouse.org/), which lets you use your heat movements to control the mouse pointer.  Not exactly what you asked about, but still in the general vicinity.  By recognizing head movements and turning them into mouse movements, this gives you the ability to activate many different programs, giving you camera control over many windows comands.

You could use [Win&I gesture control software](http://www.evoluce.com/_win-and-i/en/software/overview/index.php) for WIndows 7 and Kinect.  To specifically address your request regarding the possibility of having body movements recognized when using a powerpoint presentation, [Win&I has software specifically for using a camera for controlling a powerpoint presentation](http://www.evoluce.com/_win-and-i/en/software/overview/index.php?we_objectID=101).  Click that link to be taken to the product page.

[GestureTek](http://www.gesturetek.com/3ddepth/introduction.php) is working on multiple different solutions, and even has an SDK for programmers.

This should be a more complete answer now, considering it specifically addresses exactly what you are asking for by providing a link to software that is made for exactly what you are asking for.

Comment: Does someone have a more complete answer?

Comment: Ok. @EmRa228 I'll click on the links I provided, detail what is in them, and present more detailed information in my answer.

Comment: There are also lots of free ways to do this: [Kinect SDK's DTW gesture recognition](http://kinectdtw.codeplex.com/), [HandVu](http://www.movesinstitute.org/~kolsch/HandVu/HandVu.html), [AForge](http://code.google.com/p/aforge/), OpenCV, and [others](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26280/Hands-Gesture-Recognition), but all of these require you to write the code that performs the actions you want after the gesture capture library receives the gesture. Though FWIW, Microsoft employees have made a video showing PowerPoint controlled via Kinect, but they never released the software used.